# UIPickerView selectRow:inComponent:animated With smooth animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uipickerview

i was trying to create a Slot machine(type off slot machine but you can say at UI level it will work like Slot machine) So I use `UIPickerView` and some how i made it circular. But when i rotate it using function `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` with animated value `YES`. its animation is bit sloppy or you can say that not cool enough when we spin `UIpickerview` from hands.

Sloppy animation means, when we move `UIPickerView` with hands, it decreases its speed at the end of animation and this effect looks very good but when I use function `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` I can't get that animation.

Is there a way to get that animation???

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting the recursive description the uipickerview?
I think that some where there should be a scrollview inside. 
try getting the scrollview reference and make it scroll to the desired position with a custom animation. To get the view hierarchy try using recursive description on the picker view.
It's just a hint.
Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still relevant but as I stumbled on the same issue I made an extension for the UIPickerView with fakes the slow animation.

```
extension UIPickerView {

    func slowSelectRow(_ row: Int, inComponent component: Int = 0) {
        let currentSelectedRow = selectedRow(inComponent: component)

        guard currentSelectedRow != row else {
            return
        }

        let diff = (currentSelectedRow > row) ? -1 : 1
        let newRow = currentSelectedRow + diff
        selectRow(newRow, inComponent: component, animated: true)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
            self.slowSelectRow(row, inComponent: component)
        }
    }
}
```